# Routing vs Forwarding

Tags: routing, network

What is the difference between routing and forwarding?When the network is a packet transfer network I dont see the reason for routing since forwarding a packet between nodes requires a routing algorithm so the packet will eventually reach the destination only by the routing algorithm.

Comment: If by "routing algorithm," you mean routing protocol, then understand that routing protocols do not route packets.

Comment: Your initial question is a duplicate of previously answered question and the rest is not really clear what you are asking. Take a look at the suggested duplicate answer and then maybe reword your question if anything is still unclear.